# delete list item in pymongo collection

Tags: list, collections, pymongo

I have a users collection in pymongo and flask and inside the users collection I have the field 
"ratings":[] which takes items as input and appends them inside the list . I'm a beginner in pymongo and flask and I have trouble deleting a specific item inside the ratings list .
Let's say that I have a user instance like :

```
user = users.find_one({"name":"Bill" , "ratings":["good" , "bad"]})
```

Using :

```
user['ratings'].remove("bad")
```

returns 
TypeError: string indices must be integers

How can I delete the "bad" item inside the ratings list and what does this error mean?
I would appreciate your guidance with helping me with this task . 
Thank you in advance

Comment: You want to delete it from collection? It's not clear.

Comment: @ngShravil.py I have the users collection and a specific user has the name bill and the comments . I want to delete "bad" from the comments of the specific user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator.

```js
db.collection.update(
  { name: 'Bill' },
  { $pull:
    { ratings: 'bad' }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
del user['ratings'][1]
```

Comment: I tried for rating in usr['ratings']:
                    if request.form['movie'] in rating :
                        del usr['ratings'][rating]  It did not work

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED :                         `users.update_one({"Email":email} , {"$pull":{"ratings":rating}  })` 
did the job and deleted the user